# Surface RT doesn't show PIN pad on lock screen if keyboard detached in sleep

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, microsoft-surface

I've been seeing behavior with my Surface where if the keyboard is detached before the screen comes on (e.g. it is "asleep") then it never seems to recognize that the keyboard is no longer attached.

This is annoying if you grab the tablet, snap off the keyboard, and run off to attend other tasks. The only way to fix this is attach the keyboard again and then remove it - ANNOYING if you've left it behind!

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Any other workarounds or fixes? Thanks.

Comment: You have install all updates I assume?

Comment: Yes, everything is completely up to date.

Comment: If that is the case, it might be a bug with some nasty workaround...

Comment: Can anyone else reproduce this?

Comment: Yeah, this sometimes happens to me as well. As jocull says, only way to sort is to put the keyboard back on. I'm using RT8.1.preview.